# Printing reverse of an array

Tags: java

which is the more efficient approach to print the reverse of an array of integers in Java:

First Approach:

```
int length=array.length;
for(int j=length-1;j>=0;j--)
{
   System.out.print(arr[j]);
}
```

Second Approach:

```
List<Integer> listInteger = Arrays.asList(array);
Collections.reverse(listInteger);
int length=listInteger.size();
for(int j=0;j<length;j++)
{
      System.out.print(listInteger.get(j));
}
```

Which is the better  approach?

Comment: Well including the loop to print the array

Comment: My apologies sorry I did not see

Comment: The start of the second approach makes much more sense when followed up with `listInteger.forEach(System.out::println);`

Comment: Do you want to know what is more efficient or faster, or what is better? Or do you believe "better" = "faster", which is most often a wrong assumption? Voting to close as unclear.

Comment: I edited the question. Now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's most efficient and what is better are usually not the same thing.

The first question you should ask in this situation is how you ended up needing to traverse your data structure in reverse in the first place.  Why can't it be built in the correct order at the start?

It's far easier to fix bad code than it is to work with bad data structures.  Don't accept this situation if you don't have to.

If you have to, the next question is do you really want to couple the reversing code with the printing code?  The second approach makes much more sense when you decouple them.

```
List<Integer> listInteger = Arrays.asList(array);
Collections.reverse(listInteger);
media.display(listInteger);
```

`display` may send it to system out, or load it up in a gui, or print it on paper, or turn it into part of a web page, or ...

The first approach works when you just want a hard coded quick and dirty way to get it on the screen.

As for which is more 'efficient' the first one reuses existing memory while the second makes a copy.  If the array is huge enough for that to matter then fine.  But why the hell did you create it backwards in first place?

The first makes the computer happy and leaves me mourning the loss of flexibility.  The choice of who to make happy is up to you.

Keep in mind, premature flexibility (see BDUF vs YAGNI) is almost as bad as premature optimization.  So whatever you do, realize you've already spent too much time thinking about this.

Also, it turns out there is a better way to implement the second option.  It's detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098117/can-one-do-a-for-each-loop-in-java-in-reverse-order).